# Changing Video type by renaming

Tags: android, video, mp4

I'm trying to upload video in MS that only accept mp4 format. My problem is when I changed the video format to .mp4 by renaming it in local files iex: video.3gp to video.mp4 and my only checking is by extension. So I'm asking if is it possible to check if the video is legit .mp4? or to check if the video is not originally .mp4?

any thoughts will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: changing the extension won't change the format of the file

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, Do you have idea how to check video format except for mime type?

Comment: I believe the first few bytes of the file tell you something about the container and codec used, however thats beyond my area of expertise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video format is way too much complicated to just rename the file or change some bytes at headers. Typically if a video format has changed, it might affect:

1. Container of the video file, which means how video/audio data and metadata are contained. As you mentioned, mp4 to 3gp, etc. In this case, majority of the bitstream does not change because payload is still the same, but the format to maintain payload data changes drastically (just think about how much xml and json format differs, but they can contain same payload data).
2. Transcoding happens. In this case, video/audio data is re-encoded to other format, H.264 to H.263, MPEG-4 ASP, etc., then you can expect the new file to be a complete different file with nothing similar to the original file. Also if you play the file, subjective quality of the video can differ a lot as well since most compression is lossy.

That much being said, you need a transcoding tool to help you with what you expect to achieve. For instance ffmpeg.

In your scenario, to convert video file from 3gp to mp4 without transcoding, you can:

```
ffmpeg -i video.3gp -vcodec copy -acodec copy video.mp4
```

The output video.mp4 file is wrapped against ISO mp4 format protocol, and can be used as a 'real' mp4 file.

To determine whether a video file is which format, the most popular options are ffprobe(available from ffmpeg) and mediainfo. mediainfo might be a bit more specific on this kind of info. For instance:

```
mediainfo --Inform=General input.mp4:
```

will tell you every format related things:

```
General
Complete name                            : input.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 272 MiB
Duration                                 : 3mn 48s
Overall bit rate                         : 9 974 Kbps
Writing application                      : libte 3.0

...
```

Specifically, you can extract format info by:

```
mediainfo --Inform="General;%Format%" input.mp4, which will yield "MPEG-4" output.
```

Help this helps.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to convert it. I just need to know how can I check the video if it is a legit .mp4 and not only being rename.

Comment: Ohh Sorry, missed your question, in this case, you may want to check ffprobe or mediainfo.

Comment: Please check the edited answer whether it can solve your problem.